# struts2 switch statement

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, switch-statement

Does a solution to this problem exist in Struts2?

```
<s:if test="%{var < 50}">
   <p style="color: red;">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.</p>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="%{var == 50}">
   <p style="color: blue;">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.</p>
</s:elseif>
<s:elseif test="%{var > 50}">
   <p style="color: pink;">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.</p>
</s:elseif>
```

Ideally I would have liked to use a switch statement here, but that appears non-existent. Is there another suitable solution, instead of typing out the same line with minor changes?

Comment: Ruby on Rails and HAML: Heaven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, set a variable, and refer to it in your `style` attribute.

This has nothing to do with Struts 2 specifically, however; that's common-sense refactoring.

I don't know your usecase, but I'd prefer to see it taken a step further: the `var` value must *mean* something to your application, like "under, equal, over" or something. Rather than tie the value directly to CSS properties, let the *application*-level semantics be all you worry about in the HTML. Use CSS more-appropriately (and more flexibly) to accomplish the same thing.

```html
<p class="${answerClass}">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.</p>
```

CSS:

```
under: {
  color: red;
}

equal: {
  color: blue;
}

greater: {
  color: green;
}
```

Note that I changed the colors, using pink and red for "opposite" ends of a scale strikes me as counter-intuitive, and not so great for those that have color blindness in that color range.

The logic for selecting the CSS class name *could* exist in the JSP, but IMO it's easier to put it in the application's Java code, where it can be tested and tweaked in a wider variety of ways than if it's embedded in the view layer.

Comment: This wasn't the best example I could have given. Basically, I have a table and based on the value in each cell it should be coloured either green, amber or red... this seems like something I should be checking in the JSP rather than the Action.

Comment: @user1628194 Everything I said still stands; you're conflating presentation details with application semantics, AFAICT. In any case, setting a value based on another value is the root of what you should do. I believe the level at which you are doing it is brittle and fundamentally broken, but that's a separate issue from the refactoring itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's better use the logical part in the action. So evaluate the color value in a method.

But if you need to do this in JSP you can do also this:

```
<p style="color: 
   <s:if test="%{var < 50}">
      red
   </s:if>
   <s:elseif test="%{var == 50}">
      blue
   </s:elseif>
   <s:elseif test="%{var > 50}">
      pink
   </s:elseif>
;" >The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog.</p>
```

Just a way to avoid repetition of HTML. (DRY principle)

Comment: Can you update your answer by illustrating the use of "the logical part in the action" ?